# How to render out in VSE only a region of the frame?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I can see in VSE there is the option to render a region of the frames (and to crop).
Can you please confirm it is possible to do that and how to define the region in VSE?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the blender version that you use. The transform tools are heavily changed in version 2.92 (currently in beta). The changes are described at https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.92/More_Features and more in depth at https://developer.blender.org/rBe1665c3d31.

Before version 2.92 the use of the crop tool was problematic. Now, it works as expected and you can crop in pixel values from top,bottom, left and right.

Comment: thank you very much will try 2.92 beta